# How to subtract an IP address? ( both IPv4 and IPv6)

Tags: c#-3.0, ip-address

I have a requirement to get the number of IP addresses in an IP range identified by a startIP and an endIP both for IPv4 and IPv6 ranges.

Can anyone point to ways that can be used to achieve the subtraction of IP addresses?

The number of IP addresses will be = endIP - startIP + 1

Any responses are highly appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to clarify a little: to a zeroth approximation, you can just convert the address into a 32 or 128 bit unsigned integer and subtract those values.
However: that doesn't tell you how many distinc assignable IPs you get, because it's counting broadcast IPs and doesn't take subnets into account.

Comment: Broadcast addresses or other special addresses do not matter. My requirement is to get the arithmetic difference of two IP addresses and the data structures in C# that can hold such values ( specially ipv6).

Answer (score 2):

How's this?

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress a = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 11, 12 });
        IPAddress b = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 12, 12 });
        long diff = Difference(a, b);
    }

    private static Int64 ConvertToLong(IPAddress a)
    {
        byte[] addressBits = a.GetAddressBytes();
        Int64 retval = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < addressBits.Length; i++)
        {
            retval = (retval << 8) + (int)addressBits[i];
        }

        return retval;
    }

    private static Int64 Difference(IPAddress a, IPAddress b)
    {
        return Math.Abs(ConvertToLong(a) - ConvertToLong(b)) - 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program          
{  
static void Main(string[] args)   
    {   
        string a = "192.168.11.12";
        string b = "192.168.12.12";
        int diff = Math.Abs(IPToInt(a) - IPToInt(b)) + 1;
    } 
int IPToInt(string IP) 
{ 
    return IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(IPAddress.Parse(IP).GetAddressBytes(), 0)); 
}       
}
```